# "Number too big" when using formula with hsb color input

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw the S=1 plane through HSL color space. AFAIK, HSL colorspace is not built into pgfplots, but HSV (or HSB) is. I'm therefore trying to use the simple conversion from HSL to HSV, as follows (note the restricted x range to avoid division by 0 in this MWE).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\S{1} % saturation (S)

\begin{axis}[
    view={0}{90}, % z rotation, x rotation
    domain=0:1,
    xmin=0.1, xmax=1, % lightness (L)
    ymin=0, ymax=1, % hue (H)
    samples=30,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none},
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,},
    width=500px,
    height=100px]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp,
    mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    point meta={symbolic={hsb={y},{2-2*x/(x+\S*min(x,1-x))},{x+\S*min(x,1-x)}}},
    shader=interp] ({x},{y},{1});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I get the error,

```
! Number too big.
<argument> 0000005000000000
```

which is caused by the

```
{2-2*x/(x+\S*min(x,1-x))},{x+\S*min(x,1-x)}
```

formulae inside hsb={} (three lines from the end). I think the problem is caused by providing two-term formulae inside hsb={}. One-term formulae seem to work fine. The manual shows that without hsb={} (so that's the default RGB), two-term formulae also work fine. I am using mesh/color input=explicit mathparse. I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone have any suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: Probably some limitations of the pgf math engine. Switching calculation engine to Lua might help

Comment: The problem seems to be in the internal conversion from `hsb` model to `rgb`. Hmmm... (PS, not related, but add a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` or whatever version you have... at least >= 1.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but a hint and a workaround, too long to put in a comment; I think that the problem is in the internal calculation from "hsb" to the RGB color space. I would suggest doing the conversion to RGB yourself (I do not know the formula) to see where the conversion fails.

If you change the point meta to (notice the 0.99 in the `b` component):

```
point meta={symbolic={hsb={y},
  {2-2*x/(x+\S*min(x,1-x))},
  {0.99*(x+\S*min(x,1-x))}}},
```

to avoid the values too near to `1`, you have a correct compilation, and the output is:

[image]

(about which I have no idea if it's a sensible one)

You have also the warning `Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis z is approximately empty; enlargi ng it (it is [1.0000000000:1.0000000000]) on input line 30`, but I suppose that's expected.

---

How I found it: I discovered that the two formulas you use have no problem with calculation, as you can see here:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2.178mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\myS{1} % saturation (S)
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    domain=0:1,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    clip mode = individual,
    samples=100,
    ]
    \addplot[blue, thick] { 2-2*x/(x+\myS*min(x,1-x)) };
    \addplot[red, thick] {x+\myS*min(x,1-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated, but:

- do not use `\def\S`. If you use `\newcommand`, you'll discover that `\S` is already defined. In this case, it's not a problem, but sometimes things can explode... you can even simplify expressions and use a constant in `pgfmath`, like

  ```
   \tikzset{declare function={S=1;}}
  ```

  and then use simply `S` in the formula.
- Always add a `\pgfplotsset{compat=...}`, at least with a version higher than 1.11, which is when the defaults for coordinates in `axis` changed, or you'll have troubles some days.

Comment: Outstanding. The workaround is as good as a solution for my purposes. My bad form / laziness around pgfplotsset and def is noted and taken on board for the future. I know it's necessary, but also that I usually get away with it! tikzset declare function is a very useful feature I didn't know.

Comment: Thanks! (Ah, notice that you can put `xmin=0`, with the "0.99" it works...)